# How to make header images 50% at full screen and then stack at a certain point and begin to span full width?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 2 header images that are sharing 49% of my full width header, they are side by side. I am using a responsive skeleton theme that I have customized further. I would like the 2 header images to share half of the browser width up until a certain breaking point. The rest of my page content stacks at around 770 px. I would like the 2 header images to stack at that point and but begin to span 100% of the width.

Here is my site `http://www.stonesgamblinghall.com/dev`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Always remember to read the helpful descriptions that appear when typing tags.  Also, please include the troublesome code *in the question itself*.  We should not need to visit an external site to help you, as if that site goes down, your question becomes entirely unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should be something along the lines of:

```
.header {width:49%;}
@media screen and (max-width: 770px)
{
    .header{width:100%;}
}
```